Exercise to "dislocate the shoulder"
I watched this short video on YouTube which is called "Dislocating my shoulder for the first time (gymnastics dislocate)". It looks like this:

My questions are: Is the shoulder actually dislocated here? What are the pros and cons of the exercise?
About both points there is some disagreement in the comments. Some say the shoulder is actually dislocated, others say it's not. Further, it is said that the "ligaments will get longer and they will never be as tight to hold the shoulder correctly", while others mention the increased risk of osteoarthritis.
I will not be able to perform this anytime soon, so asking for curiosity and a better understanding of biomechanics. Thanks!

No, the shoulder is not dislocated, that's just the name of this move.   Similarly, your skull is not actually crushed in a skull-crusher exercise. Its full name is "skin the cat dislocation", and it is a variation on the more common "skin the cat" exercise, with the difference being that the traditional version uses a shoulder-width grip on the bar rather than a wide-grip, and that narrower grip prevents a complete rotation.
It's essentially just an overhead broomstick mobility exercise, except that the bar remains stationary and the body moves around it, rather than the body being stationary and the bar moving around it.
The pros of this exercise are that it looks impressive and will probably get you a lot of attention on the video sharing social media tool of your choice. The cons of this exercise are that this ability probably doesn't carry over to any other activities, so you're really just training it for the sake of being able to do it.

I am surprised that you see no effect of the exercise at all. I can't do that because I lack the shoulder mobility. I thought that too little or too much shoulder mobility would have some relevance?

The skull can get crushed if you perform the skull crusher incorrectly...

@LulY Yes it will increase your shoulder mobility in the specific form needed to perform this exercise. But to what other activities would you expect that ability to provide benefit?

@LulY David didn’t say the exercise has no effect at all. He said that this exercise has no effect besides training the specific movement of the exercise. If you want to be able to move your shoulders that way, that’s cool. But being able to move your shoulders that way isn’t going to, for example, improve your overhead press strength.

@ThomasMarkov I get this part that training the exercise helps executig the exercise. What I was wondering is what other positive or negative effects it might help. Like does it help to prevent Frozen shoulder or shoulder impingement? Or, on the other side, does it provoke actual dislocations? And so on.. I didnt await the exercise to make me strong though..

@LulY Mobility and stability of joints is a trade-off. The reason for the shoulder and the knee being so susceptible to dislocations and ruptures is, above all, that these are extremely mobile considering their structural and muscular stabilisation (Yes, the hip joint is very mobile as well but comparatively well-secured by the strongest ligaments there are and some of the strongest muscles as well as a very strong ring (labrum acetabuli) keeping it in place). Now, what happens when you stretch the ligaments and muscles around an already mobile joint beyond functional needs?

@PhilipKlöcking So you apparently see a higher risk of actual dislocations. Personally I am on the other side of the mobility-stability scale: I can't scratch my back properly.. So in my case I do exercises like the overhead broomstick stretching. After seeing this video I was wondering how far to go on with the stretching stuff. If there is a potential harm of stretching too much I gues I will stop once I can scratch my back:D

@PhilipKlöcking Besides, I thought in the case of the shoulder the stability is to a big part achieved by muscles. This would mean one can be both - flexible and stable. Flexible due to exercises as the ones above and stable due to resistance training. Or is it a wrong view about the shoulder joint?

@LulY The thing that prevents from dislocation is the passive structures in asome situations since the onset of the reflex loop (muscle spindle reflex) of the muscles can be too slow for that

@PhilipKlöcking Interesting!
